# Oracle 11 PL/SQL: check variable for null, empty string and no result

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

With PL/SQL, I perform a SELECT INTO statement, based on the result I would like to perform the same logic. I would like to check for:

- no result (0 rows returned)
- empty result (1 row with '' returned)
- null result (1 row with null returned)

In my current solution, I use a NO_DATA_FOUND exception for case 1 and IF checks for case 2+3, but call the same logic in either way, which I don't like:

```
     BEGIN
        SELECT some_value
          INTO my_variable
          FROM some_table
         WHERE somecheck = 123

        IF my_variable IS NULL OR my_variable = ''
        THEN
            ##perform logic##
        END IF;
     EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN
            ##perform same logic as above##
     END;
```

Can this be solved somehow better to prevent that I have to copy paste the same code for both, my IF check and my exception?

In particular, is it safe to extend my IF checks with

```
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN ...
```

instead of using NO_DATA_FOUND exception to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could only put the logic in the exception handler, and explicitly raise that exception on null:

```
 BEGIN
    SELECT some_value
      INTO my_variable
      FROM some_table
     WHERE somecheck = 123;

    IF my_variable IS NULL
    THEN
        RAISE no_data_found;
    END IF;
 EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        ##perform logic##
 END;
```

or get the same effect by excluding null results in the first place:

```
 BEGIN
    SELECT some_value
      INTO my_variable
      FROM some_table
     WHERE somecheck = 123
       AND some_value IS NOT NULL;

 EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        ##perform logic##
 END;
```

Not that null and an empty string ('') are the same thing so you don't need to test for both. But as you mentioned the column is actually a CLOB, you could could check for a not-null but empty CLOB by adding a check for `dbms_lob.getlength(some_value) > 0`, either to the query or before the explicit raise.

A third approach is to add a local function that performs the logic, and call that from both places in your original code.

Answer (score 2):

If you aggregate `some_value`, then you won't get `NO_DATA_FOUND` so you can omit that exception handler. `NULL` and `''` are the same, so code can be shortened to

```
select max(some_value) into my_variable ...

if my_variable is null then 
   ##perform logic##
end if;
```

Comment: Hm aggregating via MAX returns ORA-00932, inconsistent data type, clob returned but - expected

Comment: You never said it was a CLOB. Try with `select max(to_char(some_value)) into ...`

Comment: He will also silently 'avoid' too_many_rows - which probably is not desired.

Common logic can and should be extracted to procedures - there's no need for aggregation in this case.

Comment: Well, yes, @piezol; that's what the OP did initially and wanted to avoid it. We wouldn't be discussing it otherwise.

Comment: @Littlefoot No, he didn't silently avoid too_many_rows - if there is more than one row his code will throw exception - yours will silently go on.

Comment: I meant to say "too much coding", not explicitly any of possible errors.

Comment: Thanks for your input - in my case I check against a unique column so max 1 value may be retrieved